# How to trigger document fullscreen on first interaction with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

How can I go fullscreen with the whole document when someone clicks/taps on the map? I tried using the [google.maps.event.addListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=de) `dragstart` but somehow the browser rejects the fullscreen request because it needs to be initiated by a user interaction. So I guess, this event does not count as one...

On top of that, I tried all mouse events on the `<div>` container used by the Google Maps JS API, however, looks like all events are blocked/catched and none got through my separate event listener.

**How can I achieve this?**

---

*PS: The reason I want to go fullscreen with the map (and my own navigation items around it) is because on mobile devices, when draging the map downwards, the address bar shows up which messes up the viewport height and also regular map dragging with one finger.*

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. To improve your chances of getting an answer, see the Help page, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also refer to [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK, thank you for pointing that out, I'll try my best. Does the question get upvoted, once I do that or should I delete it and create a new one?

Comment: It's a good idea to edit the question rather than deleting it since you've already gotten answers. Once you edit your question, the folks who have downvoted will have the chance to take back their downvotes. They cannot undo the downvote until you edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTES**

If you want to trigger the fullscreen of the webpage on map click, then you can do the following:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
```

**JS**

```js
const docElem = document.documentElement;
const mapElem = document.getElementById('map');

mapElem.addEventListener('click',function( event ){
    // Uncomment if you do not want the default click action to happen
    // event.preventDefault();

    // Exit fullscreen if already in use
    if ( document.fullscreenElement ) 
        document.exitFullscreen();
    
    // Trigger fullscreen on document
    if ( docElem.requestFullscreen ) 
        docElem.requestFullscreen().catch( error => console.error( error ) );
})
```

Comment: This is strange, I could swear I tried this out and did not work before. But now it does when using your code... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [requestFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) API for getting fullscreen in the whole document. To get this work only on the first click, just create a variable `isClicked` for `onclick` validation on `#map` element.

```js
let map;

async function initMap() {
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}

initMap();

let mapElement = document.querySelector('#map');
let clicked = false;
mapElement.onclick = () => {
  if(!clicked) {
    mapElement.requestFullscreen();
    clicked = true;
  }
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  width: 50%; 
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
```

Comment: This works *onclick* (even though you should add an event listener rather than overriding it), however, usually you will drag the map, not click it. And the `mapELement` itself doesn't seem to be the element which is being dragged when the map is dragged, so it won't trigger *ondragstart* or not even *onmousedown*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the google maps documentation: 
[Google Developer Docs - Map Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#maps_control_positioning-javascript) 
[Google Developer Docs - Replace Default Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-replacement)

> The Fullscreen control offers the option to open the map in fullscreen mode. This control is enabled by default on desktop and mobile devices. Note: iOS doesn't support the fullscreen feature. The fullscreen control is therefore not visible on iOS devices.

```js
function initMap() {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224 },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER,
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
        },
        fullscreenControl: true,
    });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I want to whole website to go fullscreen, not just the map. Also, I could also do a button myself for going into fullscreen, but I want to avoid placing one